# Side braces - can somebody make sure I'm reading this right?

Tags: tikz-pgf, braces

After some trial and error, and a little help from this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777179/tikz-set-appropriate-x-value-for-a-node) I was able to put together this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item one length
    \tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate, yshift=0.7em] (n1) {};
    \item another length
    \tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate, yshift=-0.2em] (n2) {};
    \item the longest length
    \tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate, yshift=-0.2em] (n3) {};
    \item short
    \tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate, yshift=-0.2em] (n4) {};
\end{itemize}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \path (n4) -| node[coordinate] (n5) {} (n3);
    \path (n1) -| node[coordinate] (n6) {} (n3);
    \draw[thick,decorate,decoration={brace, amplitude=4pt}] 
        (n6) -- (n5) node[midway, right=3pt]{brace text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: side brace example]

as desired.  I am, however, a little unsure of why it works.

Do the path lines like `\path (n4) -| node[coordinate] (n5) {} (n3);` read like “make a node in the rectangular coordinate system that lines up with `n4` in x and `n3` in y”?

Comment: Yes, you read that correctly.

Comment: Instead of `node [coordinate]`, you can just use `coordinate`.

Comment: @Jake i knew `node[coordinate]` looked funny!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're basically correct, but I usually think of this slightly differently: I would say the line reads like "Make a node at the halfway position of the rectangular path that goes from `n4` to `n5`". The result is almost the same, but the distinction is that you're not just specifying a coordinate, but actually a full path, and you position a node on it.

The expressions

```
\path (0,0) -| node {X} (3,1);
```

and

```
\path (0,0) -| (3,1) node [pos=0.5] {X};
```

are equivalent, they both position a node at the coordinate `(3,0)`. The position `0.5` is defined as the halfway point on linear paths, and as the corner in rectangular paths. Using the `node` keyword between the line type (`--`, `|-` or `-|`) and the second coordinate will place the node at position `0.5`, using it between the first coordinate and the line type will place the node at position `0`, and using it after the second coordinate will place the node at position `1`.

The above expressions also both set the bounding box (and therefore the size of your picture) to include the points `(0,0)` and `(3,1)`, because you defined the whole path from `(0,0)` to `(3,1)`.

If you just want to position the node without altering the bounding box, you should use the syntax

```
\node at (0,0 -| 3,1) {X};
```

which specifies a coordinate in terms of the rectangular coordinate system between `(0,0)` and `(3,1)` without specifying the whole path.

Comment: ohhh, placement of the node keyword must be the reason it appeared to behave funny when i was setting it up.  thanks.